# Allocation of ... exeeds 10% of system memory

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I am currently having an issue with my Tensorflow model.

When starting my trained model I get the following warnings:

[image: Allocation exeeds system memory]

Tensorflow will start, but it takes 4 minutes to start and after starting it starts showing "not responding" and crashes. My guess is that this is related to the issue mentioned above.

Does anyone have a solution?

system specs:
Windows 10 64 bit,
16GB Ram,
6 cores,
Virtual machine (Hyper V)

training specs:
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS,
32GB Ram,
6 cores,
virtual machine (Hyper V)

Answer (score 1):

Did you do the math? The sizes in your screenshot alone combined are already over 20 GB. If that's on your system with 16GB RAM you are seariously swapping memory to disk, which will make everything slow/unresponsive/crash as you mention.

Solutions: add more RAM, or use less RAM...